# How to sum the array of ingredient?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to implement the `getCost()` function using a forloop but i am new to php and having trouble with understanding how to implement. i just keep getting error saying undefined variable.
 Here is my code

```
<?php 
class Burger {     
public $title = '';
private $ingredients = array(); 

    public function __construct($n) { 
        $this->name = $n; 
    } 

    public function addIngredient($ing) { 
        array_push($this->ingredients, $ing); 
    } 

    public function getCost() { 
        foreach( $ingredients as $ingredient=> $costDollars){
               $price += $costDollars;

                return $price;
 }
    } } 

class Ingredient {     
public $name = 'Ingredient';     public $costDollars = 0.0; 

public function __construct($n, $c) { 
    $this->name = $n; 
    $this->costDollars = $c; 
  } } 

$myBurger = new Burger('Tasty Burger'); 
$myBurger->addIngredient(new Ingredient('Meat', 0.3)); 
$myBurger->addIngredient(new Ingredient('Cheese', 0.2)); 
$myBurger->addIngredient(new Ingredient('Beetroot', 0.2)); 
$myBurger->addIngredient(new Ingredient('Pineapple', 0.4)); 

echo $myBurger->getCost(); ?>
```

Comment: change `foreach( $ingredients as $ingredient=> $costDollars)` to `foreach( $this->ingredients as $ingredient=> $costDollars)` you forget `$this` before `$ingredients `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting `$this` when you're trying to access the class property `$ingredients`:

```
public function getCost() {
    $price = 0;
    foreach( $this->ingredients as $ingredient){
        $price += $ingredient->costDollars;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

As you can see in the above code, the `return`-statement is also moved after the loop. If you have the `return` in your loop, the variable will be returned after the first iteration.

Comment: hey thankyou for that. What does this mean? Object of class Ingredient could not be converted to int -- at line 16

Comment: Sorry, my bad, missed that `$this->ingredients` contained a list of objects. Updated my answer.

Comment: Also should i put $price = 0 to declare it?

Comment: yup no thats perfect

Comment: Gah, I just woke up. :p Added default value for `$price`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Burger {
public $title = '';
private $ingredients = array();

public function __construct($n) {
  $this->name = $n;
}

public function addIngredient($ing, $cost) {
   $this->ingredients += array($ing => $cost); // Wont overide! EXTRA CHEEZ PLZ
}

public function getCost() {
//forloop
   $totalprice = 0;  // Start Register Cha Ching!
   foreach($this->ingredients as $ing => $price){ // Add Items (*scanner Beeps*
      $totalprice += $price;
   } // All Done with items, let return cost
   return $totalprice; // Return Value to Function Call
}
}


$myBurger = new Burger('Tasty Burger');
$myBurger->addIngredient('Meat', 0.3);
$myBurger->addIngredient('Cheese', 0.2);
$myBurger->addIngredient('Beetroot', 0.2);
$myBurger->addIngredient('Pineapple', 0.4);

   echo $myBurger->getCost(); ?> // ECHO Value to Function Call
```